# Show/hide field based on the value of another field using redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a Field which I want to hide based on the value of another Field. For this I am right now using the warn props as I can get the current value as well as the values of other fields in the form.

Is it possible to create custom props ( similar to warn and validate) that can take the current field's value and all the values of the form as arguments?

What are other approaches I can do to hide/show a field based on value of another field using redux-form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Fields`](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/fields.md/) component for this. It handles the state of various fields under a single component.

Example:

```
// outside your render() method
const renderFields = (fields) => (
  <div>
    <div className="input-row">
      <label>Category:</label>
      <select {...fields.category.input}>
        <option value="foo">Some option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    { fields.category.input.value && (
      <div className="input-row">
        <label>Sub category</label>
        <select {...fields.subcategory.input}>
          <option value="foo">Some other option</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
)

// inside your render() method
<Fields names={[ 'category', 'subcategory' ]} component={renderFields}/>
```

Comment: I thought of this, but this requires all the components in the Fields to be defined by the same component function. In my case, the fields may not be in the same vicinity. There will be multiple unrelated fields in between the two related fields.

Comment: Then you may want to connect your component and use one of the form value selectors.